# Clearing divs not working

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to clear 3 `div` in the correct manner I can do it by adding padding to the bottom of the wrapping `div` but that really isn't practical.

**[Demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/rrpv26u4/)**

What do you think the best treatment is for this?

**HTML**

```
<section class="audience">

<div class="container">

    <div class="audience_col1">

    <h1>title</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a consequat ipsum. Praesent a pellentesque nibh, vitae blandit leo. Fusce arcu orci, eleifend vel nunc vel, pellentesque eleifend lorem.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="audience_col2">

    <h1>title</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a consequat ipsum. Praesent a pellentesque nibh, vitae blandit leo. Fusce arcu orci, eleifend vel nunc vel, pellentesque eleifend lorem.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="audience_col3">

    <h1>title</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a consequat ipsum. Praesent a pellentesque nibh, vitae blandit leo. Fusce arcu orci, eleifend vel nunc vel, pellentesque eleifend lorem.</p>

    </div>

</div>    

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.audience{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f6f5fa;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.audience_col1{
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}

.audience_col2{
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 20px;  
}

.audience_col3{
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 20px;  
}
```

Comment: do not waste your time, use bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: well that isn't very constructive is it? I do not wish to use a framework...

Comment: You might love http://bourbon.io/ , http://neat.bourbon.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm right in thinking what you're trying to accomplish, why not display the `div` elements inline?

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/rrpv26u4/1/)

CSS

```
.audience {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f6f5fa;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    font-size:0; /* <--- trick to prevent inline 'spacing' of multiline HTML */
}
.audience_col1, .audience_col2, .audience_col3 {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size:14px; /* <--- revert font-size */
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I see what you did there. I will confirm the approved answer when it allows me to.

Comment: @stackers - great! Glad it was what you are after

Answer (score 1):

```
.audience{
display:block;
}

.audience_col1,
.audience_col2,
.audience_col3{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the CSS you should use if you want to work with `float` concept, else you can change the code and move ahead with the `display: inline-block` concept as shown on the other answer :-

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrpv26u4/5/)**

```
.audience{
    background-color: #f6f5fa;
}
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.audience_col1, .audience_col2, .audience_col3 {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}
```